# Установка пакетов npm

Tags: python, npm

Устанавливаю пакеты для проекта, всё ставится, папка node_modules появляется в проекте, но в последний момент, всё крушится, когда начинает выполняться скрипт для Python, в чём может быть проблема, кто-то сталкивался? Сперва установил последнею версию Pythoт, но позже нашёл информацию, что 3 версия Python не поддерживается, поэтому установил Python 2.7

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добро пожаловать! Обновите свой вопрос добавив тескт вместо картиники. Для этого нажмите [Править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1373062/edit) под самим вопросом

Comment: @Dmitry, сейчас всё правильно, я просто впервые задаю вопрос)

Comment: Да, я вижу, что в первый раз. Второй скрин у вас содержит текстовую инфу. Вот ее надо разместить в текстовый блок в вопрос. Чтобы это реализовать используйте специальные блоки, при правке вопроса можете увидеть справа подсказку

Comment: мне кажется проблема не в питоне а в мсвс

Comment: @eri, можете пожалуйста подробно объяснить, что такое мсвс?

Comment: microsoft visual studio